# Crash with pdfTron Integration iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pdftron

I am using pdfTron with iOS. I have successfully integrated PDFTron with my iOS application.

Now I am facing an issue where in if an already made annotation is selected and I try to go back from the view, the application is **crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error. I am able to see the previous screen while going back. After the previous screen appears, then the app gets crashed in main. This does not happen when I come back without the annotation being selected.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x14c78, 0x0281b3f6 myProject`___lldb_unnamed_symbol40638$$myProject + 22, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x800000a0)
frame #0: 0x0281b3f6 myProject`___lldb_unnamed_symbol40638$$myProject + 22
frame #1: 0x0250ce31 myProject`___lldb_unnamed_symbol28291$$myProject + 49
frame #2: 0x01bf03f8 myProject`TRN_AnnotIsValid + 40
frame #3: 0x01afd0ba myProject`ObjCPP_PTAnnot_IsValid + 34
frame #4: 0x01a80e0a myProject`-[PTAnnot IsValid] + 32
frame #5: 0x0199d062 myProject`-[AnnotEditTool deselectAnnotation] + 66
frame #6: 0x0198e96b myProject`-[AnnotEditTool willMoveToSuperview:] + 91
frame #7: 0x066e21ce UIKit`__UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 305
frame #8: 0x066e1ee3 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 99
frame #9: 0x019a0c09 myProject`-[ToolManager dealloc] + 73
frame #10: 0x06ef413d UIKit`-[UIView(UIKitManual) release] + 142
frame #11: 0x01a7acae myProject`-[PTPDFViewCtrl dealloc] + 588
frame #12: 0x06ef413d UIKit`-[UIView(UIKitManual) release] + 142
frame #13: 0x08e0ca57 CoreFoundation`CFRelease + 727
frame #14: 0x08e2285e CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 142
frame #15: 0x08966060 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
frame #16: 0x08965361 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 65
frame #17: 0x0896652d libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 371
frame #18: 0x08e2d508 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
frame #19: 0x08e65cdc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2364
frame #20: 0x08e650e6 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
frame #21: 0x08e64efb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #22: 0x0a49a664 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
frame #23: 0x0a49a4a1 GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
frame #24: 0x0662bbfa UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 160
* frame #25: 0x0013c23c myProject`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffaa928) + 140 at main.m:16
frame #26: 0x09e6ca21 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in the CompleteReader, or PDFViewCtrl, SDK sample projects? Also what version of PDFNet are you using?

Comment: No I am unable to reproduce this in the CompleteReader. Also I have updated my question  attaching the backtrace logs for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that Annot::IsValid does is check if the pointer is null or not. So if IsValid is crashing, then this means the underlying PDFDoc object has been destroyed, or the underlying pointer is not valid somehow.

First thing to check is if the PDFDoc object is alive or not. If it is destroyed then no objects associated with it should be used.

Or, you deleted the Annotation object earlier somehow, or its underlying pointer got changed. Object references should not be kept around in case they do get moved/deleted. If you want to retain annotations for long term, please see this [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pdfnet-sdk/X7Nh-Mx41yk/aolQGyWOAwAJ).